# Opening a second PdfReader within a using block in iTextSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I have the following code which opens a PDF and adds some text and images. At one point, I am opening a second PDF, wrapping it in an Image and adding it to the PDF. After the operation completes successfully, I want to delete the second PDF (the one I wrapped in an Image). The problem is that the file is now locked until I reset my ASP.NET application.

In the GetImageFromPdf method, you can see that I am creating a second PdfReader instance. The problem is, if I close this reader, the reader in my Create method is also closed! Am I doing something wrong? Is there another way to achieve my goal?

Here is the relevant code:

```
public void Create(string outputFilePath, bool preview = false)
{
    using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(FilePath))
    {
        using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(outputFilePath, FileMode.Create)))
        {
            PdfContentByte canvas = stamper.GetOverContent(1);

            ...

            AddMap(canvas, stamper);
        }
    }
}

...

private void AddMap(PdfContentByte Canvas, PdfStamper stamper)
{
    Image ImageWrapper = GetImageFromPdf(stamper.Writer, _MapFilePath);

    //set the position and scale the image
    ImageWrapper.ScaleAbsolute(152.5f, 152.5f);
    ImageWrapper.SetAbsolutePosition(58.5f, 197.5f);

    Canvas.AddImage(ImageWrapper);
}

...

public Image GetImageFromPdf(PdfWriter Writer, string MapFilePath)
{
    //since vector images are not supported natively by iTextSharp
    //we have saved the location maps as PDF (originally in eps format) 
    //we use GetImportedPage to import the file, and wrap it in an Image object so we can scale it

    //If I close this reader, the reader in the Create method is closed as well
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(MapFilePath);
    PdfImportedPage ImportedPage = Writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1);

    return Image.GetInstance(ImportedPage);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(FilePath),PdfReader reader1 = new PdfReader(MapFilePath))
{
pass that reader1 object to AddMap method.
}
```